# SIP Timer inside core

Tags: sip

I have below question on behavior of SIP Core in SIP communication.

Suppose party A calling party B. B receives INVITE and generates a '200 OK'. After generating '200 OK', B reaches the terminating state (SIP State Machine) and consequently there is no state machine in B.

Now if '200 OK' does not reach A, B is suppose to re-transmit '200 OK' as it has not receive ACK. RFC 3261 says it is SIP Core responsibility to re-transmit the '200 OK'.

So what is trigger in B's SIP core to send this re-transmit? Does it maintains any timers? Or is it implementation dependent?

Regards,
Sudhansu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restransmission of 2xx from B is explained in Section [13.3.1.4 The INVITE is Accepted](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)

The exact text is this one:

```
The 2xx response is passed to the transport with an
interval that starts at T1 seconds and doubles for each
retransmission until it reaches T2 seconds (T1 and T2 are defined in
Section 17).  Response retransmissions cease when an ACK request for
the response is received.
```

The end of retransmission is explained after:

```
If the server retransmits the 2xx response for 64*T1 seconds without
receiving an ACK, the dialog is confirmed, but the session SHOULD be
terminated.  This is accomplished with a BYE, as described in Section
15.
```

This means that the application layer (ie: not the transaction layer)
needs to manage the timers.

The timers T1 and T2 are defined in *table 4*: **A Table of Timer Values**.

```
T1       500ms default    Section 17.1.1.1     RTT Estimate
T2       4s               Section 17.1.2.2     The maximum retransmit
                                               interval for non-INVITE
                                               requests and INVITE
                                               responses
T4       5s               Section 17.1.2.2     Maximum duration a
                                               message will
                                               remain in the network
```

Is it allowed to modify the T1, T2 and T4 values. However, in theory, for usual Internet, they shouldn't be changed.

For example, if all ACK are lost, the retransmission would be made within those intervals:

500ms
1s
2s
4s
4s
4s
4s
...

until total is 64*T1 = 32 seconds

Comment: Expected an answer from you. Thanks clears my doubt.